# Group by singles chute

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I create an overview without duplicates in column "CHUTE"?
Eg in below result: AX002 = 129

```
select 
     COUNT(PPL_SDCC),
     substr (PPL_DISCHARGEID,6,5) as CHUTE
    
from T1LOG.PPL_PIECELOG

where 
     PPL_DISCHARGEID like 'PS%X%'
     and substr (PPL_SDCC,11,1)='1'
     and PPL_DISCHARGETIME between TO_DATE ('01/08/2021 10:00:00' , 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') and  TO_DATE ('02/08/2021 09:00:00' , 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
 
group by PPL_DISCHARGEID

order by CHUTE
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output [**in text format**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Rahther than grouping only column PPL_DISCHARGEID, You should actually include the exact calculation in group by clause. Please update your group by clause in your query to -

```
SELECT COUNT(PPL_SDCC),
       SUBSTR(PPL_DISCHARGEID,6,5) as CHUTE
  FROM T1LOG.PPL_PIECELOG
 WHERE PPL_DISCHARGEID like 'PS%X%'
   AND SUBSTR(PPL_SDCC,11,1)='1'
   AND PPL_DISCHARGETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/08/2021 10:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') and TO_DATE('02/08/2021 09:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
 GROUP BY SUBSTR(PPL_DISCHARGEID,6,5)
 ORDER BY CHUTE;
```